# PHP Ming function not working as expected (swfshape, setline())

Tags: php, flash, libming

I'm having a problem right now with a function we're using in PHP to create graphics in flash.  We recently upgraded PHP from 5.2.0 to 5.3.0 to get ready for other server upgrades and changes we're expecting.  When we did this, some of the code we use to make these graphics seemed to break.  The code for creating an objects was using swfshape::setline() to set the line's width to 0, as to hide it and not show a black border.  In 5.2, this was fine.  Now that we've upgraded, however, we're getting every object to come up with a border.  We have read over Ming and PHP documentation (which says the same thing) and it says that we can continue to pass 0 to the function for width to make the line disappear.  That doesn't seem to be the case, though.

Has anyone had trouble with this?  Does anyone know what we can do to fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an inherent problem in the ming library that we were using.  We had to manually go into the code of the library and change a few lines about how PHP was handling object creation.  Don't think it's a problem anymore, as we're no longer getting the problem.